# What's the difference between the new netstandardapp and netcoreapp TFMs?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, asp.net-core, .net-core

I noticed that NuGet has recently added support for several new TFMs related to .NET Core, including:

- `netstandard` (1.0-1.5)
- `netstandardapp` (1.5)
- `netcoreapp` (1.0)

To the best of my knowledge, `netstandard` is the .NET Core equivalent of a portable profile; it allows you to target multiple platforms using a single moniker, instead of explicitly spelling out every platform you support, e.g. `portable-net45+netcore45+wp81`.

Meanwhile, according to [this document](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-standard-applications.md) `netstandardapp` is more like a console application in .NET Core; it represents something that any .NET Core runtime (e.g. CoreCLR, CoreRT).

What, then, exactly is `netcoreapp` supposed to be? I found the tracking issue for it [here,](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2299) which includes a comment at the bottom that kinda explains what the difference is, but I don't get what the difference between

> NETStandard.Library + app hosts

and

> .NET Core base install

is. Could someone please explain it to me?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The .NET Standard Library (*netstandard*) is a consistent library across application models. .NET Core (*netcoreapp*) runs on top of .NET Standard Library and is a AppModel. From the GitHub page they answer what a .NET Standard application is and what the difference is with .NET Core (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-standard-applications.md) and (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md)

**UPDATE:** The .NETStandardapp is obsolete. The NETCore app replaces it (https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2524)

> Q: What is a .NET Standard application? 
>   A: A .NET Standard application is an application that can run on any .NET Core runtime: CoreCLR (current) and .NETNative (future). It can run on one of many .NET core platforms (Windows, OS X, and Linux). It relies on the host provided by the given runtime. It's a composable framework built from the packages on which the application depends. Its assembly loading policy permits newer versions of dependencies without any application configuration (for example, BindingRedirects are not required).
>
> Q: How is this different than .NETCore? A: The .NETCore target
>   framework represents Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Universal Windows
>   Platform applications. For compatibility purposes this moniker cannot
>   be reused for “.NET Core applications”. The branding overlap is
>   unfortunate.
>
> Q: How is this different than .NETStandard? 
>   A: The NETStandard target framework is an abstract target framework that represents API surface of many frameworks and platforms. As such NETStandard assemblies can run on any platform that supports the NETStandard targeted by that assembly, for example: .NET Desktop, Windows Phone, Universal Windows Platform applications, .NET Standard applications, etc. NETStandardApplication is a concrete target framework that represents a single platform with both API surface and implementation. .NET standard applications are runnable on their own. .NETStandard libraries must be published-for or consumed-by a specific concrete target framework to be used in that type of application.

[image: Overview of .NET Future innovation]

Comment: Can you remove your answer or at least modify it? netstandardapp is dead. See the other answer.

Comment: Updated the answer that .NETStandardapp is obsolete and NETCoreapp replaces it. Thanks

Comment: So why on earth when I create 'Class Library (.NET Core)` project do I get a reference to `.NETStandard` ?

Comment: Why .NET Core target framework represents Windows 8, Windows 8.1, and Universal Windows Platform applications? Isn't .NET Core portable? What is the diference between the _netcore_ and _netcoreapp_ TFMs at all?

Comment: There is no netcore TFM. So there isn't a difference. Yes .NET Core is cross platform. The answer is a little out of dat so i shall update it.

Comment: Ok @MartijnvanPut, 
nevertheless [this link](https://docs.nuget.org/ndocs/schema/target-frameworks) shows a netcore TFM and the [DefaultFrameworkMappings.cs](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/src/NuGet.Core/NuGet.Frameworks/DefaultFrameworkMappings.cs) file has the following code snippets: `// netcore <-> netcore45`, `// win8 <-> netcore45`, `// netcore45 <-> winrt45` and `// netcore45 -> dotnet5.2, netstandard1.1`. I still didn't understand.

Comment: @RosbergLinhares `netcore` is for UWP apps, based on dotnet plus app model specifics. Dotnet is replaced by netstandard. For Universal Windows Platform now `uap` is used.`uap10` maps to `netstandard1.4`

Answer (score 21):

> What's the difference between the new netstandardapp and netcoreapp TFMs?

`netstandardapp` is obsolete, `netcoreapp` replaces it.

> What, then, exactly is netcoreapp supposed to be?

`netcoreapp` is the target framework moniker for the .NET Core Platform. If you add `netcoreapp` to your project.json's frameworks section, then a build of your app will run on .NET Core.

> I don't get what the difference between NETStandard.Library + app hosts and .NET Core base install is. Could someone please explain it to me?

**NETStandard.Library + app hosts** is the NetStandard.App package. Do not use this - it's dead. It includes three app host packages and the standard library.

- `Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy`
- `Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms`
- `Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime`
- `NETStandard.Library`

**NET Core base install** is the Microsoft.NetCore.App package. Use this instead. It keeps two of of the above packages, scraps two of them, and adds about 37 additional `Microsoft.*` and `System.*` packages.

- Additional `Microsoft.*` assemblies
- `Microsoft.NETCore.DotNetHostPolicy`
- <s>`Microsoft.NETCore.Platforms`</s> `<-----` In April 2016, these two became
- <s>`Microsoft.NETCore.Runtime`</s> `<-------` part of the NETStandard.Library.
- `NETStandard.Library`
- Additional `System.*` assemblies

**References**

https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/2524 > States that the netstandardapp target framework moniker is "no longer valid."

https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2482 > States that "Projects targetting NetStandardApp need to be ported to NetCoreApp. NetStandardApp is not going to be supported by CLI 1.0.0 RC2."

https://www.myget.org/feed/aspnetvnext/package/nuget/NETStandard.Library > The package history shows the big change in April 2016.

Comment: When you like visualizing things in source code, you will be happy with this: https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/8939f305567e1755412d6dc0b8baf1b7. This gist was created by the architect of ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @Thomas: Extremely nice link. Short but very informative.