# How to share a .Net Core project with a .Net Core Website and UWP app?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, uwp, entity-framework-core

I'm in the process of creating a proof on concept solution that will have a shared project using Entity Framework.  I would like the shared project to be referenced by a UWP project and also by a .Net Core website.  I was able to get the Website referencing the project and using Entity Framework Core correctly.  When I try to get the UWP app to use the same code, it compiles, but fails at run time.  I've also tried changing the frameworks around using NetStandard1.4 and NetStandard1.6 but then the Entity Framework Core doesn't work correctly.

My shared project is a .Net Core class library (not an actual Shared Project type in VS).

Here's the error that I get when I run the UWP application.  It occurs when I try to create a new Context class that inherits from DbContext:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileLoadException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Here's the project.json that I have for the shared project.

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0",
    "System.ComponentModel.Annotations": "4.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    }
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }

  }
}
```

Here's the project.json for the UWP project

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform": "5.2.2"
  },
  "frameworks": {
    "uap10.0": {
      "imports": [
        "netcoreapp1.0"
      ]
    }
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-arm": {},
    "win10-arm-aot": {},
    "win10-x86": {},
    "win10-x86-aot": {},
    "win10-x64": {},
    "win10-x64-aot": {}
  }
}
```

Here's the project.json for the website project

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Domain": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "BundlerMinifier.Core": "2.0.238",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [ "bower install", "dotnet bundle" ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

Comment: It cannot be resolved out just by the json file. What is  "netcoreapp1.0", did this is your shared project? What type of this shared project? A runtime component? If you can build successfully, could you please debug where the exception throw?

Comment: I'm not sure how to explain notcoreapp1.0 but I found more info on stackoverflow question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962930/whats-the-difference-between-the-new-netstandardapp-and-netcoreapp-tfms).  Ii'll edit my post with the additional information you asked.

Comment: Hi! Which type of project did you use in order to separate EFCore? Thanks! Here is inclear what todo https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9672

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if UWP projects work well with .NET Core projects. Maybe you could try changing your EF project to a Portable Class Library project.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, please see the answer from Brice Lambson on [GitHub](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/6505)

Comment: ("Inlined" the answer.)

Comment: You can mark @bricelam's reply as answer to end up this thread.