# VS 2017 RC - Core Projects - ClassLibrary and Console - Frameworks differ

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I create a new project in VS2017 RC  I add a console lib and a class library.

now I can see that t he frameworks are added as dependencies.

but why does the core console not have `NetStandard.Library` ?

Instead I can see `Microsoft.NetCore.app`

[image]

As a result when I try to start the console app with `dotnet -run`

I get this error

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: Instead of posting images cannot you copy text directly from the prompt?

Comment: your second image didn't upload

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have the SDK/build-tools for 1.1.0 installed, but not the shared framework 1.1.0.
The SDK and the shared framework are not the same thing.

Maybe it's best explained in terms of Linux command line. 
If you had it, what you currently have installed is

```
apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1
```

but what you're missing is

```
apt-get install dotnet-sharedframework-microsoft.netcore.app-1.1.0
```

And the deeper reason is that you have 
    apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.0.1

instead of

```
apt-get install dotnet-dev-1.1.0
```

SDK version 1.1 will install shared framework 1.1.0, but if you're SDK is 1.0.1, then 1.1.0 has never been installed.

As to netstandard vs. netcore, David Fowler has a nice explanation attempt [here](https://gist.github.com/davidfowl/8939f305567e1755412d6dc0b8baf1b7).
Basically, every version of ".NET Core Framework" and ".NET Framework non-core" extend a version of netstandard, where a netstandard-library can be used in both CORE and NON-Core):

Concretely, your app can only run as either .NET Core or as .NET Framework. There is no netstandard-app (currently), only netstandard-libraries.

Both NetFramework_vX and NetCoreFramework_vX are supersets of NetStandardLibray_vX.

```
using System;

namespace Analogy
{
    // Each interface represents a target framework and methods represents groups of APIs available on that target framework. 
    // The goal is to show the relationship between .NET Standard API surface and other .NET platforms


    // .NET Standard

    interface INetStandard10
    {
        void Primitives();
        void Reflection();
        void Tasks();
        void Collections();
        void Linq();
    }

    interface INetStandard11 : INetStandard10
    {
        void ConcurrentCollections();
        void InteropServices();
    }

    interface INetStandard12 : INetStandard11
    {
        void ThreadingTimer();
    }

    interface INetStandard13 : INetStandard12
    {
        void FileSystem();
        void Console();
        void ThreadPool();
        void Process();
        void Sockets();

        void AsyncLocal();
    }

    interface INetStandard14 : INetStandard13
    {
        void IsolatedStorage();
    }

    interface INetStandard15 : INetStandard14
    {
        void AssemblyLoadContext();
    }

    // .NET Framework 

    interface INetFramework45 : INetStandard11
    {
        void FileSystem();
        void Console();
        void ThreadPool();
        void Crypto();
        void WebSockets();
        void Process();
        void Sockets();

        void AppDomain();
        void Xml();
        void Drawing();
        void SystemWeb();
        void WPF();
        void WindowsForms();
        void WCF();
    }

    interface INetFramework451 : INetFramework45, INetStandard12
    {
        // TODO: .NET Framework 4.5.1 specific APIs
    }

    interface INetFramework452 : INetFramework451, INetStandard12
    {
        // TODO: .NET Framework 4.5.2 specific APIs
    }

    interface INetFramework46 : INetFramework452, INetStandard13
    {
        // TODO: .NET Framework 4.6 specific APIs
    }

    interface INetFramework461 : INetFramework46, INetStandard14
    {
        // TODO: .NET Framework 4.6.1 specific APIs
    }

    interface INetFramework462 : INetFramework461, INetStandard15
    {
        // TODO: .NET Framework 4.6 specific APIs
    }

    // Mono

    interface IMono43 : INetFramework46
    {
        void MonoSpecificApi();
    }

    // Windows Universal Platform

    interface IWindowsUniversalPlatform : INetStandard14
    {
        void GPS();
        void Xaml();
    }

    // Xamarin 

    interface IXamarinIOS : INetStandard15
    {
        void AppleAPIs();
    }

    interface IXamarinAndroid : INetStandard15
    {
        void GoogleAPIs();
    }

    // .NET Core

    interface INetCoreApp10 : INetStandard15
    {

    }

    // Future platform

    interface ISomeFuturePlatform : INetStandard13
    {
        // A future platform chooses to implement a specific .NET Standard version.
        // All libraries that target that version are instantly compatible with this new
        // platform
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the difference between netcoreapp and netstandard please check: [What's the difference between the new netstandardapp and netcoreapp TFMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36962930/whats-the-difference-between-the-new-netstandardapp-and-netcoreapp-tfms).

When you run `dotnet -run` on the command line you need to have installed the .NET Core SDK, which is a seperate installation of .NET Core. Installing VS2017 RC doesn't install this SDK. You can download the .NET Core 1.1 SDK [here](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#windowscmd)