# What is the difference between `.NET Core` and `.NET Core App`?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-core

Looking at the [Target Frameworks Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/target-frameworks), I see the TFM `netcore`, which corresponds to `.NET Core`, and the TFM `netcoreapp`, which corresponds to `.NET Core App`. What is the difference between these two frameworks?

Comment: The answer on [What's the difference between the new netstandardapp and netcoreapp TFMs?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36964558/5395709) may help you.

Comment: It helped a bit, but it seems out of date. As far as I can tell, `netcoreapp` wasn't a thing back then. But maybe that's the answer. `netcore` is UWP/win8 and `netcoreapp` is the .NET Core platform that runs on Windows/Linux/macOS. In which case, those TFMs are really annoying.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Framework Profiles in .NET](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/05/framework-profiles-in-net.html)

The `netcore` TFM is the Windows Store .NET Framework, and is roughly similar to the equally versioned .Net Framework.

The `netcoreapp` TFM is cross platform .NET Core.

Comment: So if the world was sane, the former would be `winstore` or something and the latter would be `netcore`